# "Message Preview" in GMAIL is showing alt text

Tags: html, gmail, html-email, alt

I created an HTML Email Template that works fine in most email clients. As expected, I have `alt` and `title` attributes in different elements.

My problem is that GMAIL is reading those `alt` or `title` attributes and including its content in the email preview section.

I tried to follow these instructions [here](https://support.google.com/mail/forum/AAAAK7un8RUk6-hQhhQRXU/?hl=en), but having a Plain Text email didn't solve my problem.

*For reference, this is what I mean by "Email preview" (for privacy reasons, I can't screenshot my email):*

[image]

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, that's a really good reading! I agree that having a good alt text will help, but good alt text not necessarily means a good preview text, IMO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you need is called `pre header` or `preview text`. This is hidden text placed just after the body tag in a div

```
<div style="display:none;font-size:1px;color:#{color};line-height:1px;font-family:{font};max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;">
    Pre header/Preview text here&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;&nbsp;&#847;
</div>
```

Things to note:

- If you want to keep it blank, simply remove the text '*Pre header/Preview text here*'
- if you want to keep the pre header then use the above code as is.
- Change color and font family based on your needs.(text color should be same as background color of email).
- If you alt text still shows, append the div content with `&nbsp;&#847;` until you get what you are after.

Here is character count for preview text based off different devices.

[image]
[Source](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-marketing/preview-vs-preheader-text-how-long-should-preheader-text-be/)

Comment: Thanks, that does the job. My only comment is that we should use `<td>` instead of `<div>`, since Outlook (desktop app) doesn't work well with `<div>`s

Comment: Only if you want to display divs. In this case the div is hidden with CSS. Also if you get a change look into hybrid/spongy coding technique for email's. It uses divs.

Comment: But doesn't Outlook delete the divs, instead of just hiding it? (I will take a look into that, thanks)

Comment: I have never encountered Outlook deleting div's yet. Which version deletes it?

Comment: Oh, was more of a question. It is the desktop app version, so I can't really inspect anything. I just noticed that using `div` with styles didn't work, but using the same styles in `<table>` worked.

Comment: That is correct, Outlook totally ignores styles on div and keeps the ones on `td` (or `table`)

Comment: I would only add that if you do use the &nbsp;... that this can be a flag for spam and should be used with caution. This was coming from someone who worked with SpamAssassin so it's not a vague 'maybe', but a real thing

Comment: Noted Nathan. I haven't faced it yet but will keep a look out for it if it happens.